# Time Series Clustering: problem to converting a dplyr data frame into a list of time series

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, dtw

I'd like to use time series clustering using the `dtwclust` package. The problem is the conversion of my data.frame to list of time series. All my blocks ID (named `STAND`) has 180 days in negative values (`DATE_TIME`) The `B2_MAX` is my variable response. In my example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dtwclust)

all.B2_MAX.stands <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/my_ts_data.csv")

all.B2_MAX.tsc <-  all.B2_MAX %>%
  group_by(STAND) %>%
  summarise(var = list(B2_MAX[order(DATE_TIME)]), 
            var_ts = purrr::map(var, ts))

clusters <- tsclust(all.B2_MAX.tsc[-1], 
                   type="partitional", 
                   k=2L, 
                   distance="dtw",
                   centroid = "pam")

#plot
plot(cluster, type = "sc")

#Error in lapply(series, base::as.numeric) : 
#  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Please, any help with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case `split` by response variable and idBlocks after using the `tsclust` function, work very well:

```
d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/my_ts_data.csv")
l <- split(d$B2_MAX,d$STAND)
o <- tsclust(l, 
        type="partitional", 
        k=2L, 
        distance="dtw_basic",
        centroid = "pam")
#plot
plot(o)
o

# partitional clustering with 2 clusters
# Using dtw_basic distance
# Using pam centroids

# Time required for analysis:
#   usuário   sistema decorrido 
#      1.13      0.00      0.16 

# Cluster sizes with average intra-cluster distance:

#   size       av_dist
# 1   14 3.518299e+198
# 2   50  4.526561e+08
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to come from the construction of time series. The `ts` function requires a numeric vector, while your `var` is a list of lists.

Try unlisting the `var` first using the `unlist()` function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dtwclust)
library(purrr)

all.B2_MAX.stands <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/my_ts_data.csv")

all.B2_MAX.tsc <-  all.B2_MAX.stands %>%
  group_by(STAND) %>%
  summarise(var = list(B2_MAX[order(DATE_TIME)])) %>% 
  mutate(var_ts = purrr::map(var, ~ts(unlist(.))))

clusters <- tsclust(all.B2_MAX.tsc$var_ts, 
                   type="partitional", 
                   k=2L, 
                   distance="dtw",
                   centroid = "pam")

#plot
plot(clusters, type = "sc")
```

Comment: Thanks @Marwi, but unfortunately doesn't work. The error now is in the `tsclust` function (`Error in dtw(distance.only = TRUE, ...) : 
  No warping path exists that is allowed by costraints`).